# Split key value in map scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I don't know if it is possible, but I'd like in my mapPartitions to split in two lists the variable "a". Like here to have a list l that stores all numbers and an other list let's say b that stores all words. with something like `a.mapPartitions((p,v) =>{ val l = p.toList; val b = v.toList; ....}`

With for example in my for loop l(i)=1 and b(i) ="score"

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val a = sc.parallelize(List(("score",1),("chicken",2),("magnacarta",2)) )

a.mapPartitions(p =>{val l = p.toList;
    val ret = new ListBuffer[Int]
    val words = new ListBuffer[String]
    for(i<-0 to l.length-1){
    words+= b(i)
    ret += l(i) 
    }
ret.toList.iterator
}
)
```

Comment: `a.map(_._1); a.map(_._2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a distributed computing engine. you can perform operation on partitioned data across nodes of the cluster. Then you need a Reduce() method that performs a summary operation.

Please see this code that should do what you want:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {

  class MyResponseObj(var numbers: List[Int] = List[Int](), var words: List[String] = List[String]()) extends java.io.Serializable{
    def +=(str: String, int: Int) = {
      numbers = numbers :+ int
      words = words :+ str
      this
    }

    def +=(other: MyResponseObj) = {
      numbers = numbers ++ other.numbers
      words = words ++ other.words
      this
    }

  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val a = sc.parallelize(List(("score", 1), ("chicken", 2), ("magnacarta", 2)))

    val myResponseObj = a.mapPartitions[MyResponseObj](it => {
      var myResponseObj = new MyResponseObj()
      it.foreach {
        case (str :String, int :Int) => myResponseObj += (str, int)
        case _ => println("unexpected data")
      }
      Iterator(myResponseObj)
    }).reduce( (myResponseObj1, myResponseObj2) => myResponseObj1 += myResponseObj2 )

    println(myResponseObj.words)
    println(myResponseObj.numbers)

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution but I don't know how to launch it ?
I tried with :load test.scala ( test .scala = name of my file)
But it only displays that everything is well loaded (I code with the terminal in Windows and NotePad++)

Comment: I would recommend to download an ide such intellij or eclipse and install a scala plugin .